# Need javascript to show specific comment boxes on form based on dropdown choice

Tags: javascript, forms, drop-down-menu, comments

I'm trying to figure out how to show a specific comment box based on a dropdown.
I want to have a form with a dropdown box with options of 0-10.

If any number from 0-9 is chosen, a single question with a comment box should be shown (same question/box whether it's 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8 OR 9).

If 10 is chosen, a different question and comment box will show.

I know there is a clean/elegant way to define 0-9 in one "group" that shows one box and hide that and show the other box if 10 is shown, but I can't seem to get it.

Answer (score 0):

Put the questions 0-9 in a div and the question 10 in another div and hide both. Link the onselect event of the dropdown to your script. Inside the script grab the selected item from the dropdown and if it's between 0-9 make the first div visible or if it's 10 make the second div visible.